# What I can use instead of GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

What I can use instead of gridview or how can I speed up loading?
How to build something like stackoverflow using for showing data? Is anyone has example with code source?

Comment: What's wrong with GridView? How much data are you trying to show?

Comment: Please don't duplicate the tags ("Asp.Net C#") in the title. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow uses ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET.  If you use ASP.NET MVC, you can use a simple `foreach` loop over a collection object in the `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

The Repeater is the fastest of the databinding controls available to you in asp.net webforms ([even by Microsoft's own tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx)).